# Argument of \@item has an extra }

Tags: errors, sphinx

I get the error

```
! Argument of \@item has an extra }.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.135 \emph{class} \bfcode{C}}
```

when translating a LaTeX file generated by [Sphinx](http://sphinx-doc.org/) documentation system.

I've managed to reduce it to the following self-contained example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\newcommand{\pysigline}[1]{\item[#1]\nopagebreak}

\newenvironment{fulllineitems}{
  \begin{list}{}{\labelwidth \leftmargin \labelsep 0pt
                 \rightmargin 0pt \topsep -\parskip \partopsep \parskip
                 \itemsep -\parsep}
}{\end{list}}

\begin{document}

\begin{fulllineitems}
\pysigline{\phantomsection\label{index:project0class_c}\item[] template \textless{}typename T\textgreater{}
\emph{class} \bfcode{C}}
Test class. 
\end{fulllineitems}

\end{document}
```

As you can see the '{' and '}' are balanced.

What does this error mean and how can I fix it?

Comment: Can you post some sort of minimal, compile-able example?  For instance, there's no way for us to know (right now) that the `\item` is indeed inside some sort of list environment (where it would cause an error outside of one).

Comment: impossible to be sure without working example but I wpould gues that `\pysigline` puts its argument in an optional argument so use `\pysigline{{...}}` to hide the `[]`

Comment: You should work a little and try to reduce the code to the minimal necessary to reproduce your error. Then post it here.

Comment: @SeanAllred OK, now I've reduced it to a self-contained example.

Comment: The brackets are balanced but you are passing an arg to `\pysigline` that contains an `\item` so after substituting it to `#1` you get something like `\item[...\item...]` which is not valid

Comment: @DavidCarlisle You're right; would you mind posting that as an answer?  **EDIT** ... more or less...

Comment: @SeanAllred answer added I was constrained yesterday:-) http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/17694997#17694997

Comment: @DavidCarlisle You are a man with your priorities in order.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A LaTeX optional argument ends at the first `]` (unless it is inside a `{}` group. It does *not* match `[ ]` (unless you use the declarations provided by `xparse`)  so in

```
... \item[...\foo[] ...]  zzz
```

the argument of `\item` is not `...\foo[] ...` but `...\foo[` and things go wrong.

`\pysigline` puts its argument in an optional argument so use

```
\pysigline{{...}}
```

to hide the `[]`

Or better (if you have access to the definition in your real case) fix the definition to add the extra `{}` in all cases:

```
\newcommand{\pysigline}[1]{\item[{#1}]\nopagebreak}
                                 %  %
```

now a stray `]` in the argument to `\pysigline` is protected from terminating the optional argument of the inner `\item`