# Command that seems to not be able to unravel the command given in argument

Tags: macros, arguments

I am trying to define some new commands to be able to define default values for some of the things I will be using over and over again in order to centralize where the style and the typical letter used should be defined.

The things that I have so far and that gives some trouble is the following

```
\newcommand{\Prob}[1]{%
    \IfEqCase{#1}{%
        {1}{p}%
        {2}{q}%
        {3}{r}%
    }[#1]%
}%
\newcommand{\RandomVar}[1]{%
    \IfEqCase{#1}{%
        {1}{X}%
        {2}{Y}%
        {3}{Z}%
    }[#1]%
}%
```

And an example of use is

```
$p_{\RandomVar1, \RandomVar2}$, $\Prob{p_{\RandomVar1,\RandomVar2}}$
```

The goal of all this is to be able to have default values for probability distributions, default values for random variables, and to also be able to provide a different value than the default ones if needed. Here the first code works and produces $p_{X,Y}$, the second one doesn't and produce the following error

```
I've run across a `}' that doesn't seem to match anything. For example, `\def\a#1{...}' and `\a}' would produce this error.
```

I think that the problem is similar to that of [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/201270/argument-of-item-has-an-extra) but I couldn't work around a solution, I tried putting braces around things without really understanding what I was doing. Any help would be welcome.

---

Complete example

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xstring}

\newcommand{\Prob}[1]{%
    \IfEqCase{#1}{%
        {1}{p}%
        {2}{q}%
        {3}{r}%
    }[#1]%
}%
\newcommand{\RandomVar}[1]{%
    \IfEqCase{#1}{%
        {1}{X}%
        {2}{Y}%
        {3}{Z}%
    }[#1]%
}%

\begin{document}
$\Prob1$, $\Prob2$, $\Prob{p_{X,Y}}$, $p_{\RandomVar1, \RandomVar2}$

$\Prob{p_{\RandomVar1,\RandomVar2}}$

\end{document}
```

The first line of the document yields

```
$p$, $q$, $p_{X,Y}$, $p_{X,Y}$
```

The last line should yield

```
$p_{X,Y}$
```

but instead gives an error.

Comment: always show a small but complete example. Don't let people guess or search which packages you use.

Comment: Sorry, but it isn't clear what you're expecting. You're passing `\Prob` the argument `p_{\RandomVar{1},\Randomvar{2}}` which is definitely not 1, 2 or 3. But there are other problems with `xstring` (which are the cause of the error).

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Sorry about that, please find it included at the end of the post.

Comment: @egreg Maybe the full code helps, so basically if 1,2,3 is provided it should give the associated value, otherwise it should give the given argument.

Comment: @P.Quinton But you *never* pass 1, 2 or 3 to `\Prob`.

Comment: As much as I love centralization, I don’t think this is the right approach. Why not have three commands `\RandomVarX`, `\RandomVarY`, and `\RandomVarZ`? Then you can change their definition and control their look from the preamble. And if you later want to change their names to “A”, “B”, and “C”, you can change their definition. You can even string replace `\RandomVarX` by `\RandomVarA`, etc. using your editor if you want the syntax to reflect the notation better. That will hardly require much more typing than your current method.

Comment: @egreg I could pass 1,2,3 to \Prob but not in this short code, because it doesn't trigger the error that I am trying to fix.

Comment: @Gaussler well imagine the same thing but with essentially 10 of those and commands that compose them together. For instance I have one that does measure space defined as $(\Set{#1}, \SigmaAlgebra{#2}, \Measure{#3})$, but also many more usefull things, for those I want to be able to use predefined values for simplicity (typically in proofs) but I also want to be able to specify something else if I want. Observe that by combining several of those the amount commands in your suggested method can grow quite fast. Anyways any help on that particular error is most welcome.

Comment: @P.Quinton And is it a problem to have many commands? I don’t see how it is worse than having many tests in one command.

Comment: Re-reading the question after having had some sleep I realize that it is not clear whether you generally wish to compare the tokens of `#1` as they are or whether your intend is to crank out the case of `#1` not forming a TeX-<number>-quantity whose value is in range 1..3.  I.e., what do you want to get with `\newcount\mycnt \mycnt=3` and `\Prob{\the\mycnt}`? Do you want to get `\the\mycnt` → `3`? Do you want to get `r`? (The latter requires testing whether tokens (after expansion) form a valid <number> quantity whereby a test reliable in all situations seems not feasible to me.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems making commands robust by defining via `\NewDocumentCommand` instead of `\newcommand` does the trick.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{xstring}

\NewDocumentCommand{\Prob}{m}{%
    \IfEqCase{#1}{%
        {1}{p}%
        {2}{q}%
        {3}{r}%
    }[{#1}]%
}%
\NewDocumentCommand{\RandomVar}{m}{%
    \IfEqCase{#1}{%
        {1}{X}%
        {2}{Y}%
        {3}{Z}%
    }[{#1}]%
}%

\begin{document}
$\Prob1$, $\Prob2$, $\Prob{p_{X,Y}}$, $p_{\RandomVar1, \RandomVar2}$

$\Prob{p_{\RandomVar1,\RandomVar2}}$

\end{document}
```

The last line yields `p_{\RandomVar1,\RandomVar2}` which in turn yields `p_{X,Y}`.

[image]

---

A better approach might be using expandable `\str_case:nnTF`:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new:Npn \Prob #1 {%
  % \exp_args:Ne fully expands the argument passed to \str_case:nnTF.
  \exp_args:Ne
  \str_case:nnTF {#1}
    {
      {1} {p}
      {2} {q}
      {3} {r}
    }
    {}
    {#1}
}
\cs_new:Npn \RandomVar #1 {%
  % \exp_args:Ne fully expands the argument passed to \str_case:nnTF.
  \exp_args:Ne
  \str_case:nnTF {#1}
    {
      {1} {X}
      {2} {Y}
      {3} {Z}
    }
    {}
    {#1}
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
$\Prob1$, $\Prob2$, $\Prob{p_{X,Y}}$, $p_{\RandomVar1, \RandomVar2}$

$\Prob{p_{\RandomVar1,\RandomVar2}}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer.

Comment: @P.Quinton egreg's answer is better than mine as 1) it uses `\str_case:nnF` instead of `\str_case:nnTF` 2) it provides abstraction. In order to do a favor to those who might in future encounter this question while searching for answers I suggest unaccepting my answer and accepting egreg's.

Answer (score 3):

You can define your `\Prob` and `\RandomVar` very simply using expandable TeX primitive `\ifcase`:

```
\def\Prob #1{\ifcase 0#1\or p\or q\or r\fi}
\def\RandomVar #1{\ifcase 0#1\or X\or Y\or Z\fi}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it looks nice but I turned out to accept the other one because of the minimal amount of things I had to change.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is in how `xstring` processes its commands, using *full expansion* unless explicitly told otherwise.

This is the cause of failure of `\Prob{p_{\RandomVar{1},\RandomVar{2}}}`, because `xstring` tries to fully expand `\RandomVar{1}` which cannot survive `\edef`.

The `\str_case:nnF` function in `expl3` hasn't this problem. Since you seem to want to define several commands in a similar fashion (return from a list of choices when the argument fits, or return the full argument), abstraction seems useful.

```
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\definechoicemacro}{mm}
 {% #1 = macro name, #2 = choices
  \NewDocumentCommand{#1}{m}
   {
    \str_case:nnF { ##1 } { #2 } { ##1 }
   }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\definechoicemacro{\Prob}{
  {1}{p}
  {2}{q}
  {3}{r}
}
\definechoicemacro{\RandomVar}{
  {1}{X}
  {2}{Y}
  {3}{Z}
}

\begin{document}

$\Prob1$, $\Prob2$, $\Prob{p_{X,Y}}$, $p_{\RandomVar1, \RandomVar2}$

$\Prob{p_{\RandomVar1,\RandomVar2}}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you prefer to define the macros individually,

```
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new_eq:NN \choosefromordefault \str_case:nnF
\ExplSyntaxOff

\newcommand{\Prob}[1]{%
  \choosefromordefault{#1}{
    {1}{p}
    {2}{q}
    {3}{r}
  }{#1}%
}
\newcommand{\RandomVar}[1]{%
  \choosefromordefault{#1}{%
    {1}{X}
    {2}{Y}
    {3}{Z}
  }{#1}%
}

\begin{document}

$\Prob1$, $\Prob2$, $\Prob{p_{X,Y}}$, $p_{\RandomVar1, \RandomVar2}$

$\Prob{p_{\RandomVar1,\RandomVar2}}$

\end{document}
```